# How to get an instance for a previously migrated contract with truffle?

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-contract

Scenario:

1. Token contract migration file
2. Dapp contract migration file

I want to interact with the already deployed token contract in the dapp contract migration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy. Assuming you successfully deployed your token contract in a previous file (e.g. `2_migrate_token.js`), here's a basic example for `3_deploy_dapp.js`:

```
const ERC20 = artifacts.require("./ERC20.sol");

module.exports = async (deployer) => {
  let erc20Instance = await ERC20.deployed();
  // interact with the token contract
  return deployer.deploy(DappContract);
};
```